# LAMP without PHP

Tags: server, mobile, lamp

My question is that is the P part of the LAMP really necessary? 
I will have the database and I can connect to it via the appache http so why will I need php/python in the server side (if it is a really simple set up)

also from a seperation of concern it might be more robust at least thertically to leave the P out of the equation and to use LAM only.

What are you guys think? I need to build this as a linux server in order to backend mobile ios and android.

cheers

Comment: "avoid asking subjective questions where …

    every answer is equally valid" ([help/dont-ask]). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: Is it 'necessary' *for what*?  LAMP is just an acronym that describes one particular type of app hosting stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “P” part of a LAMP stack is a layer of CGI scripts. This layer can be provided by a number of languages. While PHP is the most common of these, other languages such as Perl or Python can be used as well.

While a LAMP architecture is common and robust, it may not actually match your needs. For example it might make sense to not use CGI scripts and leave out the “A” (Apache HTTP Server), and use a more integrated web framework of your language of choice instead. When using Perl, a common stack would be to utilize Linux running a Perl application built around the Mojolicious web framework, using Starman as a server and PostgreSQL as a DB, and running behind Nginx as a caching proxy. Which stack to choose depends directly on the project you are tackling, and on the technologies you (and your team) are familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

LAMP is just a convenient platform.  If part of it doesn't fit your needs -- like, for example, you need run a windows server for $REASONS -- then replace that part.